# Nginx Lua Scripting

Tags: nginx, lua

One of the really cool things about Nginx is that you can take control of what it does by injecting Lua script at various phases of request processing.  I have successfully used the rewrite_by_lua/file directive to examine the body of the incoming request and inject extra request headers for downstream processing by PHP.  e.g.

```
location /api{
  rewrite_by_lua_file "/path/to/rewrite.lua";
  lua_need_request_body "on";
```

}

and then in `rewrite.lua`

```
local uri = ngx.var.request_uri;
//examine the URI and inject additional headers
ngx.req.set_header('headerName','headerValue');
```

What I *can* also do at this stage is inject response headers.  For example

```
local cookieData = "cookieName=value;path=/;";    
ngx.header['Set-Cookie'] = cookieData;
```

No issues thus far but this is not quite what I want to do.  The workflow I have in mind goes like this

- Examine the URI & inject extra **request** headers.
- My PHP scripts examine the extra request headers, process the incoming data as required and **may** inject extra response headers
- I then want to examine the response headers in another Nginx Lua script and inject cookies at that stage.

Injecting extra response headers via my PHP script is no problem at all. I thought that in order to examine those extra headers I would just need to setup

```
location /api {
  header_filter_by_lua_file "path/to/header.lua";
}
```

with `header.lua` doing things like

```
local cookieData = "cookieName=value;path=/;";    
ngx.header['Set-Cookie'] = cookieData;
```

The principle sounds perfect.  However, I find that my `header_filter_by_lua_file` directives just get ignored - no errors reported in the Nginx log when I reload the configuration.

I must be doing something wrong here but I cannot see what it might be.  I am using `nginx 1.6.2` on Ubuntu 14.10 (x64).  Nginx having been installed with `apt-get install nginx-extras`.

I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to explain how to get `header_filter_by_*` functioning correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a feature of vanilla nginx. You need to install openresty (instead of nginx).

See http://openresty.org/#Download and then http://openresty.org/#Installation

Comment: I don't have Vanilla Nginx.  I have [Nginx-extras](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nginx-extras) installed on Ubuntu.  My understanding is that this is Nginx with the lua module installed. As I say in my question `rewrite_by_lua_file` and `ngx.` both work just fine. The issue is with `header_by_lua...`. Are you suggesting that the latter is only available with OpenResty not _even_ with **Nginx Extras**?